# css list drop down menu bar moves when I zoom and resize browser window

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I created a drop down menu bar in lists and css and anytime I zoom in/out or adjust browser window size the contents on the bar shift to the left when zoom out and right when zoom in. Also, when I adjust the browser window size the navigational bar doesn't move with the rest of the page to the left. So if someone opens a new browser window and it's smaller than a full screen, the contents in my navigation bar would be in the wrong place (too far left or right). Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you for any help in advance. I did research previous questions that were similar to mine but it seems any time I try those solutions they don't work for me.

Here's the link for the menu bar I've created.
http://www.stlpublicradio.org/info/press-test.php#

```
<code><div id="wrapper">
<ul id="nav">

<li>

<a href="#">main menu 1</a>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
           </ul> 
</li>


<li>
        <a href="#">main menu 2</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5/a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>

<li>
        <a href="#">main menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
 </li>

<li>
        <a href="#">main menu 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>




</ul>
</div>

</code>

<code>
THE CSS
#wrapper {
width: 100%;

}

#nav{ 
    background: #383838; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 21%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,      color-stop(21%,#383838),   color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 21%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 21%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 21%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #383838 21%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left:500px;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav li a{
    border-left: thin;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-width:thin;
    border-left-color:#cccccc;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 100%;    
}

#nav li{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-top:0;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    color: #99CCCC;
}


#nav a{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav a:hover{
    margin-top:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}


/*dropdown start*/
#nav ul{
    height: 400px;
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);     
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    padding-left: 275px;
    padding-top:0px;
    display:block;
    width: 190px;
    /*display:block;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font: bold;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;*/
}

#nav ul li{
    text-align:left;
    float:none;
    margin-left: 275px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav li a img {
    padding-left: 3px;
}

#nav ul a{
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color:#333;
    white-space:nowrap; 
}

#nav li ul li a {   
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#nav li a {
    color: #cccccc;
}

#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0;
    display: block;
    left:-275px;
}

#nav li:hover a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#333;
}
    </code>
```

Comment: Browser zoom is crap and breaks lots of things. Don't sweat it.

Comment: It won't move with window resize (or gets messed up) most likely because of the `padding-left: 500px` - why is that there? The desired effect can likely be accomplished in another way that won't break

Comment: Is there a better way you recommend?

Comment: Hay how did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `nav` you have `padding-left: 500px;`, that's a lot of padding and will cause you issues on smaller screens and browser resizing.

Comment: Is there a better way you can recommend?